# How to create a dictionary for a 10,000 dataframe records and then access each dictionary record to make some calculations?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a panda dataframe that has 10,000 records. The dataframe consists of 0 and 1 and looks like this:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4 
0   0  1  1
0   1  0  0
1   0  1  1
```

My aim is to make each record as a dictionary which I assign a value for the dictionary for each column (each column has the same value):

```
   C1        C2         C3      C4 
{0: 10}    {0: 11}   {1: 15}  {1: 13}
{0: 10}    {1: 11}   {0: 15}  {0: 13}
{1: 10}    {0: 11}   {1: 15}  {1: 13}
```

and then access the dictionary and make some calculation row by row and compare between the total of `0`  and the total of `1`. The number with the highest value will be added to a new column. For example for the first row `0 = 21` and `1 = 28` therefore `1` will be added to the new column. The second row `0 = 38` and `1 = 11` therefore  `1` will be added:

```
   C1        C2         C3      C4       New_column
{0: 10}    {0: 11}   {1: 15}  {1: 13}        1
{0: 10}    {1: 11}   {0: 15}  {0: 13}        0
{1: 10}    {0: 11}   {1: 15}  {1: 13}        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need the intermediate dicts, you can do some multiplications and sums:

```py
values = [10, 11, 15, 13]

zeros = df.eq(0).mul(values).sum(axis=1)
ones = df.eq(1).mul(values).sum(axis=1)
df['New_column'] = ones.gt(zeros).astype(int)

#    C1  C2  C3  C4  New_column
# 0   0   0   1   1           1
# 1   0   1   0   0           0
# 2   1   0   1   1           1
```

And if you do want the dicts, I would do it backwards and create the dicts *after* computing `New_column`:

```py
df[['C1','C2','C3','C4']] = df.filter(like='C').apply(
    lambda column: [{x:values[df.columns.get_loc(column.name)]} for x in column])

#         C1       C2       C3       C4  New_column
# 0  {0: 10}  {0: 11}  {1: 15}  {1: 13}           1
# 1  {0: 10}  {1: 11}  {0: 15}  {0: 13}           0
# 2  {1: 10}  {0: 11}  {1: 15}  {1: 13}           1
```

Comment: The first method worked perfectly. May I know why you used `.mul`?

Comment: @s_am In this case it's mainly just personal preference because I think chained methods are easier to read/write than nested parentheses: `((df == 0) * values).sum(axis=1)`. In other cases the Series methods like [`mul()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) and [`eq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) are useful for their params like `axis`, `level`, and `fill_value`.